# Joining tables that have no common value

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to join 3 tables for a system to keep track of what comes in and out of my shop.

The first tables is as following. (Production)

```
id
Amount
Date
item id
```

next table is: (sales)

```
id
date
amount
customer id
amount
```

the last is: (waste)

```
id
date
amount
reason
```

I haven't really found a way to join those 3 tables without using a common value they could join on.  I need to order them by date so I can see the history of my income and expenses. If the 3 different tables could come with a individual value like 3 for waste 2 for sales and 1 for production would also be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not a `join` of the tables but a `union`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Something like

```
(SELECT 'production' as source, id, Amount AS amount, Date AS date FROM Production)
UNION 
(SELECT 'sales' as source, id, amount, date FROM sales)
UNION 
(SELECT 'waste' as source, id, amount, date FROM waste)
ORDER BY date;
```